# How will pixel widths look on resolutions beyond

Tags: css

If I have all widths on my website set to 1920px

How will it look on higher resolutions (4k for example)? Will it only fill a portion of the site and leave the rest white around it (because this is what happens when I zoom out)?

I guess what I'm really asking is: If I think about the whole website as an image, can I scale it all at once keeping proportion?

EDIT: After some research and trying, i solved it by setting width to 100% and view height (vh) after my needs.

Comment: If you set the width to 1920, the width will always be 1920, regardless of the size of the browser window. If you want it to be scalable you should be using percentages and then set 1920 as the `max-width` rather than the `width`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CSS3 values spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths), `px` is an absolute physical length and is supposed to map to approximate real-world dimensions:

> The reference pixel# is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with
>   a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm’s
>   length. For a nominal arm’s length of 28 inches, the visual angle is
>   therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm’s length, 1px thus
>   corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).

This means that the device itself should be scaling your `px` measurement appropriately for the display - in terms of 4k, you'll likely see 4 physical pixels for each CSS pixel. This is usually user-configurable in the operating system though, so that isn't a guarantee.

Hardcoding the width of a site is usually a bad idea though - what happens when the browser isn't full screen? How does it appear on mobile devices? You should consider using [relative length units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative-lengths) like `%` and `em` to make your layout more flexible and adapt to these situations.

Comment: There is also the setting on the `viewport` meta of pixel density, which may influence this answer.

Comment: My main problem is with the images, I tried with percentages earlier but the image always gets messed up or outside of the page when I change to smaller resolutions. And it's not even scrollable, they just go outside the browser window.

Comment: @Chumppe - Can you post an example? Talking about the problem in generic terms may not help much. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and see if you can update your question with more details.